# need to replace a file contents

Tags: sed, aix

I am stuck in a situation. I have a file script.txt with contents

```
$cat script.txt

SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 3
-- IGNORE ROLLFORWARD CONTAINER OPERATIONS
USING (
FILE '/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'  5120
);


SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 4
-- IGNORE ROLLFORWARD CONTAINER OPERATIONS
USING (
  FILE   '/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'  5120
);
```

My requirement is the filesystems in the lines

```
FILE '/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg' 5120
FILE   '/db2data1/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'  5120
```

I need to replace

```
/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg
```

and

```
/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg
```

with other filesystems; say

```
/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg
```

and

```
/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg
```

respectively.

Other parts should be the same. My output be such that the lines be now--

```
FILE '/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'  5120
FILE '/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'  5120
```

It should reflect in my file. I don't know the position of the lines in the line. I tried with sed. I tried to put the lines into variables say var1 and var2

```
var1=`echo /db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'
var2=`echo /db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'
var3=`echo /db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'
var4=`echo /db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'
```

when I tried to do

```
sed 's/$var/$var3' script.txt
```

it fails as / is there. I am using AIX. 
My final files should be like this--

```
SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 3
-- IGNORE ROLLFORWARD CONTAINER OPERATIONS
USING (
FILE '/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'  5120
);


SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 4
-- IGNORE ROLLFORWARD CONTAINER OPERATIONS
USING (
  FILE   '/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'  5120
);
```

Answer (score 7):

When there is a `/` in the text you can use a different character, for example a `|` as the separator for the sed arguments. Also, when using variables, you need to use double quotes (`""`) for the `sed` command because variables aren't expanded within single quotes. Try this:

```
var1='/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'
var2='/db2data2/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'
var3='/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest1.lrg'
var4='/db2data3/dbs/rahtest/rahtest2.lrg'

sed -e "s|$var1|$var3|g" -e "s|$var2|$var4|" script.txt
```

Comment: Added explanation of why

Comment: Thanks you Michael Durrant, terdon and Jonathan Leffler for the improvement of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To robustly handle variable information in regular expressions you need to escape the regular expression metacharacters. This question has been answered many times - I've done it personally many times myself - but here's the lowdown anyway:

```
^$*[]\.
```

^These are basic regular expression metacharacters. Each of these have special meaning in a regular expression as *syntax* and are not interpreted literally. The significance of several of these are actually position dependent and so you sometimes *may* get away with including them in a regular expression without proper escaping but that doesn't mean you *should* - especially when the regular expression is built of unvalidated input.

But there's more:

```
delimiter newline &
```

^These are `sed` `s///`ubstitution substitution syntax characters. The delimiter - which is traditionally `/` - is variable and `sed` will automatically interpret it to be the first character following an `s` for a new command.

The newline - on the left-hand *regular expression* side of the statement - is positively unescapable. It is invalid there. The only way to substitute a newline is to use the `\n` escape - but the only way to *get* a newline in pattern space that might be found in a regular expression is to put one there yourself - and so that is usually not a problem. On the right-hand side of the `s///`ubstitution - the *replace* side - the newline is escapable - like all else - with `\`, which is the escape metacharacter. The same is true for `&`.

And so to build a robust `sed` script of variables you need to escape it. That's the only way. Altering the delimiter because you expect there might be one in your statement is not a robust method. Either you validate input and rule out any chance of syntax errors, or you escape syntax characters to mean what you intend. Those are the two ways to write robust programs - there are no others.

Fortunately, `sed` makes it very easy. As mentioned - the `\` backslash is the escape metacharacter and will even escape itself when doubled. And so we can use `sed` to escape `sed`.

```sh
printf %s\\n "$regex_field" "$replace_field" |
sed -ne'h;n' -e's|[\&/]|\\&|g'               \
    -ex      -e's|[]/\.$^*[]|\\&|g'          \
    -eG      -e's|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|s/\1/\2/|p' |
sed -f-      edit_file
```

See? The input is separated on newlines - and so, as written, makes no allowance for a newline in either of `$regex_field` *or* `$replace_field`. You *could* handle that as well, but this doesn't and so the expectation is input will be validated to rule it out.

In any case, the input lines are fed the first `sed` in pairs, and it `h`olds a copy of the first half of each pair of lines and skips `n`ext to the second, when it escapes the characters relevant to the right-hand-side of a `sed` `s///`ubstitution statement. It then e`x`changes its hold and pattern spaces and escapes the left-hand-side, before `G`etting the RHS appended to the LHS as separated by a `\n`ewline delimiter. The last thing it has to do is add the `s///` bits before `p`rinting the escaped command to standard-out.

The second `sed` reads its script file on `-` *(which is generally interpreted to mean standard-in, but you may want to try `/dev/fd/0` if not)* and  then applies that script to its named *`edit_file`*.